# Read Description list in selenium python

Tags: python, html, django, selenium

How can I read text of `<dd>` tag which has `<dt>` like Commodity code.

```
`<dl class="dl">
        <dt>Trading Screen Product Name</dt>
        <dd>Biodiesel Futures (balmo)</dd>
        <dt>Trading Screen Hub Name</dt>
        <dd>Soybean Oil Pen 1st Line</dd>
        <dt>Commodity Code</dt>
        <dd><div>S25-S2Z</div></dd>
        <dt>Contract Size</dt>
        <dd><div>100 metric tonnes (220,462 pounds)</div></dd>
</dl>` 


from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python36-32\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")
link_list = ["http://www.theice.com/products/31500922","http://www.theice.com/products/243"]
driver.maximize_window()
for link in link_list:
    driver.get(link)
    desc_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("dl")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement below code to get the values of `"Commodity Code"` as output:

```
for desc_list in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("dl"):
    print(desc_list.find_element_by_xpath("./dt[.='Commodity Code']/following-sibling::dd").text)
```

Comment: print(desc_list.find_element_by_xpath("./dt[.='Commodity Code']/following-sibling::dd").text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Comment: Yep, right. I didn't notice that `desc_list` is a list :) Check updated

Answer (score 0):

To extract/read the text of `<dd>` tag which has child `<div>` tag e.g. **S25-S2Z** you can create a *List* of the desired elements and then print the text within the elements and you can use the following solution:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//dl[@class='dl']//dd/div"):
    list_dd.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```